# How to transfer execution control from textbox to user control when user pressed enter/numpad6 key?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I have written code to paint 4 rectangles on user control, next to 1 rectangle there is 1 textbox. I wanted to transfer execution control from textbox to user control(in which I wrote code for rectangles) after pressing enter/numpad6 key by entering text in textbox. I written code in textbox keydown event but it won't work.If any any find solution please let me know.

Comment: Show your code please.  And is this winforms or web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not complete answer to your question but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157106/keydown-event-how-to-easily-know-if-the-key-pressed-is-numeric) So question will give you clue how to know that user has pressed the Numpad 6 key.