# Common Function to validate keypress event for multiple texboxes in windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Can we created common function to check keypress event and restrict user to enter only numeric entries for multiple textboxes in windows form?

Can we create something like below:

```
private void txtsample1_keypress(...)
{
  call validate()
}

private void txtsample2_keypress(...)
{
  call validate()
}

public void validate()
{
  Here, validation for multiple textboxes
}
```

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157106/keydown-event-how-to-easily-know-if-the-key-pressed-is-numeric  and also it might be a good idea to check this in KeyUp rather than KeyPress ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Note you probably want `IsDigit(char)` rather than `IsNumber(char)`, as discussed in [Difference between Char.IsDigit() and Char.IsNumber() in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228532/difference-between-char-isdigit-and-char-isnumber-in-c-sharp/228565#228565).

```
public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtsample1.KeyPress += ValidateKeyPress;
    txtsample2.KeyPress += ValidateKeyPress;
}

private void ValidateKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // sender is the textbox the keypress happened in
    if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) //Make sure the entered key is a number (0-9)
    {
        // Tell the text box that the key press event was handled, do not process it
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can even register the same event on all your text boxes and process them all through one.

```
    void txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)) //Make sure the entered key is a number
            e.Handled = true; //Tells the text box that the key press event was handled, do not process it
    }
```